# mod_auth_kerb.so: undefined symbol: ap_log_error

Tags: load-balancing, kerberos, centos6, httpd.conf, mod-auth-kerb

I have 3-node cluster, On first node i have installed my service in kerberos enabled mode. 
For load-balancer, on second node i have installed httpd 2.2.15 version, apr 1.5.2 and apr-util 1.5.4 and "./configure" , make, make install command was executed successfuly.
To enabled kerberos, i have install mod_auth_kerb.so module and also added in httpd.conf, and im restarting the apache service using "./apachectl restart" it give me an error

> httpd: Syntax error on line 80 of /usr/local/apache2/conf/httpd.conf:
>   Cannot load /usr/lib64/httpd/modules/mod_auth_kerb.so into server:
>   /usr/lib64/httpd/modules/mod_auth_kerb.so: undefined symbol:
>   ap_log_error

Comment: Which version of apache are you using ? mod_auth_kerb.so doesn't seem to be compatible with it.

Comment: Apache version 2.2.15